# mouse hover only works the first time with IE driver

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Webdriver/Selenium 2 with C# question - I am doing a mouse hover to make some elements visible for clicking. I tried it with the firefox driver with erratic results, so I switched to the IE driver and it seems to work. However, it only works the first time. I do a hover, click an element, it works. I attempt another hover and it does not hover. Anyone seen this ? I am using C#

```
    private void MouseHover(IWebElement element)
    {
        Actions builder = new Actions(Driver);
        builder.MoveToElement(element);
        builder.Perform();
    }

       //mouse hover on settings menu
        MouseHover(_pagedriver.FindElement(By.Id(TopLevel.settingsmenu)));

        //click first setting
        _pagedriver.FindElement(By.Id(TopLevel.settingone)).Click();

        //mouse hover on settings
        MouseHover(_pagedriver.FindElement(By.Id(TopLevel.settingsmenu)));

        //click second setting
        _pagedriver.FindElement(By.Id(TopLevel.settingtwo)).Click();
```

It works fine for the first time, but the second time there is no mouse hover so it can't click on the second item.

Comment: Does the element that you click on cause a postback? Some example code would help. When you say that the hover does not work, does the generated HTML still show the appropriate attributes for your element?

Comment: updated with code. It never manages to click the second item because of ElementNotVisibleException

Comment: the first and second items to be clicked are links to other pages

Comment: Are you sure the hovered element is still visible the second time?

Comment: The hovered element is not visible the second time and that is the issue. The mouseover works the first time but not the second time.

Answer (score 0):

There are known bugs with mousover in webdriver/selenium2

http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2067